# can multiprocessing referred function use dataframe as parameter

Tags: python, dataframe, multiprocessing

I have a function(populate_fits) which use a dataframe as parameter. And I have multiple similar dataframes needing this function to process in parallel.

```
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
results = [pool.apply(populate_fits, args=(raw_df)) for raw_df in raw_dfs]
```

However, it report error like follow:

TypeError: populate_fits() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given

Comment: What are raw_dfs and raw_df? If raw_df is a 4-tuple, Python is right when raising the error.

Comment: Are you simply missing the comma: `args=(raw_df,)` ?

Comment: raw_dfs is a list of dataframe, raw_df is a dataframe. raw_df surely contains 4 columns. Does Python not take raw_df as a whole?

Comment: It workes when adding the comma, amazing.